# ID disk from event message

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, usb, event-log

I have the following event in Event Viewer:

```
"The driver detected a controller error on \Device\Harddisk6\DR19."

Log Name: System
Source: Disk
EventID: 11
Level: Error
```

How do I know what disk this is referring to? I am reasonably confident that it is a plugin USB memory stick, but want to be sure it is not one the of the main HDD's. When I plug a USB stick into the slot, diskpart shows the arrival of "Disk 6". I am presuming that Disk 6 corresponds to Harddisk6 in the controller error, but I don't like assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

How to Distinguish a Physical Disk Device from an Event Message

https://support.microsoft.com/kb/159865

Comment: Dan, thanks for your response, but the detail in this KB doesn't match Win 7. As an example, the "DR" component in the error message I get isn't mentioned at all. There is also detailed registry refernces in that KB that just don't exist in Win 7. I have seen this KB referenced several times, quite often with requests for more recent information. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

*Method 1 Computer Management*:
Open Computer Management (compmgmt.msc)
Expand Storage
Click on Disk Management
Right-Click on your hard disk(s)
Review the General tab and the Location field

*Method 2 Registry Editor*:
Run the registry editor (regedit.exe)
Drill down to the following path:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\Scsi\Scsiport0

Use the "identifier" and "DeviceType" values, determine which entries are for DISKS and which are for other devices such as CD-ROMS, tapes, scanners, and so forth.

> Scisbus0
>  
>   Targetid0 > Logical Unit Id 0   look at identifier and type.
>   Targetid1 > Logical Unit Id 0   look at identifier and type.
>   Targetid4 > Logical Unit Id 0   look at identifier and type.
>
> Scsibus1
>   Targetid0 > Logical Unit Id 0   look at identifier and type.
>   Targetid1 > Logical Unit Id 0   look at identifier and type.
>   Targetid2 > Logical Unit Id 0
>
> ...

Find each DeviceType:REG_SZ:DiskPeripheral entry under the Targetid#\Logicalunitid0. Each one found equates to a drive in Disk Administrator and also to a \device\harddisk number.
To find \device\harddisk6 find the 7th DiskPeripheral (zero through five)

More: http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/159865

*Method 3 Diskpart*:
Open and elevated command prompt/PowerShell window
Type **diskpart** and press enter
Type **list disk** and press enter (you can also type **list volume** for a list of all volumes)
 
Review the output

*Method 4 WMI in PowerShell*:
Open and elevated PowerShell window
Type **gwmi win32_diskdrive | select *** and press enter
Review the output

*Method 5 WinObj*:
More:  http://www.mysysadmintips.com/windows/clients/472-find-which-drive-letter-corresponds-to-device-harddiskvolume